# No route matches {:controller=>"items", :action=>"complete", :list_id=>1, :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

So localhost works. When I click on "show" for a list, the URL goes to localhost/lists/1 and throws the error above.

here is my routes.rb file:

```
resources :lists do
  resources :items
end

match 'lists/:list_id/items/:id/complete' => 'items#complete', :as => :complete_item

root :to => 'lists#index'
```

here is my show.html.erb file (lists view):

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @list.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @list.description %>
</p>

<ul>
    <% @list.items.each do |item| %>
    <li><%= item.name %> <%= button_to "Complete", complete_item_path(@list.id,item.id) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<%= form_for [@list, @item] do |form| %>
<p><%= form.text_field :name %> <%= form.submit %></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_list_path(@list) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', lists_path %>
```

here is my items_controller.rb file:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    attr_accessor :completed

    respond_to :html, :xml, :js

    def create
        @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
        @item = @list.items.new(params[:item])
        if @item.save
            flash[:notice] = "Item was created."
            redirect_to list_url(@list)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Could not add item, try again later."
            redirect_to list_url(@list)
        end
    end 

    def complete
        @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
        @item = @list.items.find(params[:id])
        @item.completed = true
        @item.save
        redirect_to list_url(@list)
    end

end
```

This is what I get when i run rake routes:

```
    list_items GET    /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)              items#index
               POST   /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)              items#create
 new_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/new(.:format)          items#new
edit_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id/edit(.:format)     items#edit
     list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)          items#show
               PUT    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)          items#update
               DELETE /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)          items#destroy
         lists GET    /lists(.:format)                             lists#index
               POST   /lists(.:format)                             lists#create
      new_list GET    /lists/new(.:format)                         lists#new
     edit_list GET    /lists/:id/edit(.:format)                    lists#edit
          list GET    /lists/:id(.:format)                         lists#show
               PUT    /lists/:id(.:format)                         lists#update
               DELETE /lists/:id(.:format)                         lists#destroy
 complete_item        /lists/:list_id/items/:id/complete(.:format) items#complete
          root        /                                            lists#index
```

here is my schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130412080044) do

  create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.boolean  "completed",   :default => false
    t.integer  "list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
  end

  add_index "items", ["list_id"], :name => "index_items_on_list_id"

  create_table "lists", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end
end
```

show action of lists_controller.rb

```
def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @item = @list.items.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @list }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why is your Item ID nil? Can you make sure its not nil.

Comment: try this : <% @list.items.each do |item| %>
      <% next unless item.id %>
      <li><%= item.name %> <%= button_to "Complete", complete_item_path(@list.id,item.id) %></li>
    <% end %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to use a parameter hash for the complete_item_path method:

```
complete_item_path( :list_id => @list.id, :id => item.id)
```

The second thing is that there is an unsaved item in the @list.items collection. You'll need to ignore that when generating the links:

```
<ul>
  <% @list.items.each do |item| %>
    <% if item.id %>
      <li><%= item.name %> <%= button_to "Complete", complete_item_path(@list.id,item.id) %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: How would I be able to tell where it occured?

Comment: One other thing, in the "form_for [@list, @item]", where does "@item" come from? Can you post the controller code of the show action? If that one is an unsaved object that's already in the "@list.items" association, that could create the error too. You'd need to wrap an "if !item.new_record?" around the <li> tag then.

Comment: You could post the complete error stacktrace. There should be a line indicating in which file the exception occured.

Comment: Ok, this is the second problem: "@item = @list.items.new". This one will create an unsaved Item in the @list.items collection that doesn't have an id yet. So you have to wrap your <li> tag in an "if item.id" or "if !item.new_record?" to ignore it in the list.

Comment: Yes! I just added your code and refreshed and it works. How did you know there was an unsaved item?

Comment: because of this line in the controller: "@item = @list.items.new". You created that for the form below, but it's also added to the "@list.items" collection, but not saved to the database yet.

Comment: How would I go about preventing this type of error in the future?

Comment: you could create the item like this: "@item = Item.new" and add a hidden field with the list_id to the form: "<%= form.hidden_field :list_id, :value => @list.id %>". That way the unsaved item wouldn't be added to the collection.

Comment: Is there is a way to check the database for this unsaved item via the console?

Comment: Or don't add the hidden field at all. You don't need it, as you create the item in the "create" action like this anyway: @item = @list.items.new( params[:item])".

Comment: No, the unsaved item isn't in the database, hence "unsaved".

Comment: No, you need it for the form at the bottom of the page. There's no need to clear it as it only lives as a temporary object within the request handling. You just need to make sure that it doesn't interfere with the rest of the code on that page.

Comment: Oh I gotcha. Do you know of any documentation related to this issue?

Comment: It's all the lines that the rails server writes to the console if an error occurs.

Comment: I guess you started the server in a terminal with "rails s"? That's where the debugging output goes.

Comment: Do you have your own blog or website I could check out?

Comment: Oh well you totally should start your own rails blog, with your experience, I get the feeling people would eat it up. You could talk about fringe error scenarios that you've encountered, etc. Anyway, lemme know when you do. Do you have a Twitter account?

Comment: There's no way to direct message users on here so I figure I could keep in touch via Twitter or email?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28147/discussion-between-bedroomfireflys-and-lassej)